# Change from windows 10 to windows XP or win7

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-xp, bios, dell-inspiron

ogether with greeting you, I wanted to ask you the following question. I was formatting a computer from the Inspiron 15 3000 that has windows 10 and I wanted to format it and pass it to windows XP, but I get the following error:

**the bios in this system is not fully acpi complian ...**

Attached photo of the error:

[image]

this is the bios photo:

[image]

[image]

I hope someone has some idea and can help me format and change from wind10 to windXP, please.

Comment: besides googling the error and trying solutions suggested..  while the error rings a bell, I don't recall, but perhaps it might make a difference to experiment between switching boot list option between Legacy and UEFI but perhaps first try what tim suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior can occur if Windows has detected that the BIOS in the computer is not fully compliant with Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI).

Disable it!
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314830/-stop-error-code-0x000000a5-error-when-you-are-installing-windows-xp

Make sure drivers are available on dells support for Windows XP. Or your video and perepherals will be useless. (Most computers made past win7 do not have XP supported drivers!)

Comment: I'm adding this comment because it's opinion based, I have no idea why the user would want to go back to XP. This is a bad idea.with no support from Microsoft, windows XP has become very susceptible to viruses, malware, ransomware, etc. It's also lacking security features on the network side. And generally lacks any support for new hardware. I'm sure other users could chime in to give more reasons not to do this.